# Detect whether public IP address is dynamic or static

Tags: smtp, ip, ip-address, detection

There are several email servers refusing connections of clients with public dynamic IP addresses. For example many smtp servers receiving emails only accept connections to clients having static IP adresses to avoid spam emails which are directly sent from computers having dynamic IP addresses.

When I looked for answers using google I only found information saying it is impossible to distinguish between static/dynamic addresses. So how do the email servers do it? Are there any databases providing information for specific IP ranges?

Have a look at the MX records of `t-online.de` (one of the largest German email providers). Try to connect to `mx00.t-online.de:25` using Putty (raw mode) on a computer having a dynamic IP address. The mail server immediately closes the connection and does not even allow the client to send any command, while a connection of a server having a static IP is not refused.

Or have a look at the following extract of a SMTP session:

```
220 mailin.rzone.de [joses mi173] ESMTP RZmta 29.19 ready
EHLO Home-PC
250-mailin.rzone.de [joses mi173] greets 87.179.163.89
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-DELIVERBY
250-SIZE 104857600
250 HELP
MAIL FROM:<sender@example.com>
250 2.1.0 <sender@example.com> Sender ok
RCPT TO:<recipient@example.org>
550 5.7.1 87.179.163.89 is a dynamic IP
```

This is the email server for customers of Strato, a German hosting company, which also denies access to clients having a dynamic IP address. Email addresses have been changed. I used a recipient address which is acceptable for `mailin.rzone.de`, so there is no relay issue.

Also http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check states the following:

> Just because the IP is listed with a particular blacklist does not
>   mean that you are sending spam, just that particular blacklist
>   suggests not to accept mail directly from that IP address. Most
>   residential Cable/DSL IP addresses that are [dynamically assigned](http://whatismyipaddress.com/dynamic-static) will
>   indicate that they are blacklisted, meaning you should be sending from
>   your ISP's mail server, not a mail server running on your own internet
>   connection.

Comment: I suspect there's some confusion of terminology somewhere in the background to this question.  It might improve your chances of an answer if you restated the first paragraph of your question.  It would especially help if you pointed to specific instances of email servers that refuse connections (ideally by pointing to their documentation or some other web page that explains their rules).

Comment: I wouldn't expect `mailin.rzone.de` to allow you to relay, which is what the example shows.

Comment: I have only exchanged the email addresses for security/privacy purposes ;) As recipient address I used my own real email address, which is valid/acceptable for `mailin.rzone.de`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the result of using a DNS blacklist based on ISP-provided information about which of their IP addresses are authorized to send email directly.  See Spamhaus' [Policy Block List](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/) for an example.

**The information isn't independently discoverable.**  Participating ISPs must provide the DNSBL services with information about their network.

However, in the case of some of these lists, like Spamhaus, the information is queryable by the general public under certain conditions.  You couldn't detect whether IPs are static or dynamic directly, but could still check any particular IP.

You mentioned that whatismyipaddress.com incorrectly lists your current IP address as static.  Using [their blacklist check tool](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) with your IP, 87.179.190.52, I see that they currently incorrectly show it as unlisted by Spamhaus' PBL (among others).  The IP I'm connecting from is both correctly described as dynamic, and listed in the PBL, hinting that that might be what they're basing their information on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those email servers you're referring to only do a reverse DNS check so as long as you have a PTR record for that IP address, I think it *should* be OK.

Bottom line, I don't think dynamic IP allocation is an issue with mail servers.

Regarding the question, the only way I can think of is by looking at the WHOIS information, there's a field called `NetType`. Obviously, you cannot rely on it but at least it can give you an idea if the ISP did provide that information.

Comment: I updated my answer and added two examples of email servers which deny access to clients having a static IP address. The method they use must be very reliable as otherwise many emails would be blocked.

Comment: I still don't think any SMTP server by itself would block a dynamic IP address. Based on the information you added to the question, I think it may be one of the "blacklist" projects, perhaps something like: [SORBS - Dynamic User and Host List](http://www.sorbs.net/delisting/dul.shtml)

Comment: According to a blacklist check, my dynamic IP address is only blacklisted by `cblless.anti-spam.org.cn`. But http://whatismyipaddress.com states that my IP address was static which is not correct.

Comment: What's your hostname? (you can mask the sensitive parts if necessary)

Comment: My hostname is currently `p57b3be34.dip.t-dialin.net`.

Comment: One possibility is to look for an indication that this is a dynamic IP based on the hostname. SORBS mentioned that if a removal is requested, as long as your hostname doesn't indicate that it's a dynamic IP, they would remove it. I've seen many ISPs use the word "pool" to indicate it's a dynamically allocated IP. In your case, "dip" stands for "Dynamic IP" (it's a known thing, actually). This is of course just a possibility.

Comment: Where does one find this `NetType` field? What WHOIS is this from?

Answer (score -4):

Static/public ip addresses are listed by some ISP's as follows
123.123.123.4 static.yourisp.isfine.com

WHILE dynamic are listed:
123.123.123.5 dhcp.mx1.coldservice.com

see?